# bash file looping and passing contents to java call

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script and it isn't quite working right.  The objective here is to move XMLs from /source to /active folders, then call a java script and pass in XML file contents as argument, then move active file from /active to /archive folder.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash 
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_02 
CLASSPATH=/tracking/lib/tracking_client.jar: .
FILES=/tracking/source/*
for f in $FILES
do
  filename=$(basename "$f")
  cd /tracking/source/
  mv /tracking/source/${filename} /tracking/active/${filename}
  cd /tracking/active/
  $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH TrackClient  ## need to pass XML file contents in to java call as argument
  mv /tracking/active/${filename} /tracking/archive/${filename}
done
exit 0
```

Comment: What is not working right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$()` to insert the result of a command into the command.

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH TrackClient  "$(cat "/tracking/active/${filename}")"
```

Comment: Do the move, copy and loop commands look good to you?  Not sure about command line options.

Comment: `for f in $FILES` will not work correctly if any filenames have whitespace or wildcard characters in them. And I'm not sure why you need the `cd` commands, but they're harmless.